# I'm trying to make a simple code that delets a string (user input) from a linked list

Tags: pascal

Basically I don't know how to stop the destruction of my list after "dispose(death)" because I keep getting this internal error that I couldn't understand, I'd appreciate any help!

```
L := Start;

write('what are you looking for: '); readln(S);

L:=Start;

while (L <> nil) and (L^.char <> S) do
begin

  if L^.char = s then
    death := L;

  L:=L^.next;

end;
Dispose(death);
```

Error message:

> Project pro raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'. At address 100002AE6

Comment: Please put your code directly in the question as formatted text

Comment: The while loop continues as long as `L` is assigned and `L^.char <> s`. This means that `L^.char` never can be equal to `s` and consequently, `death` will never be assigned. So, when the loop ends, you will dispose of an unassigned pointer, hence the sigsegv error.